# Getting 'Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.' When Keyboard appears

Tags: flutter, dart

I use currencyPicker for selecting currency and save that into hive and updated the UI.
When try to search on the picker's search bar ,the following error occurs.

**Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.**

Here is my code

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    try {
      showCurrencyPicker(
        context: context,
        showFlag: true,
        // showCurrencyName: true,
        // showCurrencyCode: true,
        onSelect: (Currency value) {
          setState(() {
            currency = value.code;
            settings['Currency'] = value.code;
            settingsBox.put('Settings', settings);
          });
        },
      );
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print('$stackTrace ////////////');
    }
  },
  child: CContainer(
    text: 'Currency',
    widget1: CText(
      text: currency,
    ),
  ),
),
```

I've attached screen recording that shows what is exactly happening.

[Screen Recording](https://streamable.com/7hf5wg)